# I want to create a folder navigation in PHP

Tags: php, browser

i want to create a data browser where i can navigate through data based on a apache and Mysql server. How can i list data form a selected folder? is this possible in PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: i want to create spaceship - ples provide full plans

Comment: why did i get two dislikes?

Comment: to broad and ambiguous

Comment: i think it should be clear what i want

Comment: please spend a moment or 10 in the help section

Comment: The web is a wonderful resource. Without having to ask a human anything, you can type into a search engine words like "list folder php" and find thousands of resources. If you then get stuck on something specific, feel free to come here and ask for help, but make sure to look at the [help] pages first.

Comment: some of us even managed to research before the web existed ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing folder contents can be done in numerous ways using PHP, from a very simple glob() cmd to a complicated(?) recursiveIterator.

```
Example of glob.
----------------
$dir=realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/folder' );
$col=glob( $dir . '/*.*' );
print_r( $col );
```

Comment: thank you! Now i know for what i have to search :)